# update values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
list_dict = [
        {'name': 'Old Ben', 'age': 71, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['getting wise']},
        {'name': 'Han', 'age': 26, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['shooting']},
        {'name': 'Luke', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['being arrogant']},
        {'name': 'R2', 'age': 'unknown', 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': []}
    ]
```

I would like to add a hobby to R2:

```
for i in range(len(list_dict)):
    people = list_dict[i]
    if people['name'] == 'R2':
        people['hobbies'] = ['lubrication']
print(list_dict)
```

I got what I was expecting but as a newbie I'd like to learn a few easy tricks to make it shorter.

Comment: Iterate over the list no need to use range `for d in list_dict`, other than that this is good. You could change your data structure to provide faster updates for each dictionary but no much

Comment: Make your life easier by using a dict of dicts with the names as keys. Then you can just do: `list_dict['R2']['hobbies'].append(hobby)`.

Comment: @user1166251 :I am just curious if you asked for shorter code - this is how I understood your question. Would be glad if you check out my answer and provide some feedback on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd express as:

```py
people = {person['name']: person for person in list_dict}

people['R2']['hobbies'] += ['lubrication']  # reads nicely as "add a hobby to R2"
```

For all those hung up on the academic concern of "potential people with same name", although the "Leetcode answer" would be:

```py
for person in list_dict:
    if person['name'] == 'R2':
        person['hobbies'] += ['lubrication']
```

But in practice, remodeling data to have & use primary keys is probably what you want in most cases.

Comment: if there are more R2s this doesn't change them all.

Comment: Sure, I'm assuming people are uniquely named. If they're not, can change impl to group by name, i.e. `Dict[str, List]` instead.

Comment: For the sake of picking a 'name' as most important key in the dictionary you get redundant data. It's not a win at all and not worth to use in context of the question. And if you make it accepting more individuals with same name you have to loop over the items of the List making things more complex again. *I suggest not to use the in this answer proposed approach.*.

Comment: ... @Claudio do you criticize database indexes for being "redundant data" too?

Comment: @Kache : the question was how to make the loop code shorter, not how to improve the data structure ( for some imaginary from context inferred purpose which may not be the right approach as you notice from the objection that not all R2's are updated ),

Comment: @Kache: imagine that you want to find all individuals with the lubrication hobby and you use the proposed data structure which allows duplicate names (that is why it is a list of dictionaries and not just a dictionary with the name as key, what would be the really right approach if you want to change the data structure). You will need to loop over the dictionary values and then over the items in the value.

Comment: @Kache use `.append(x)` instead of `+= [x]`

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the list and condense the if statement:

```py
for person in list_dict:
    person['hobbies'] = ['lubrication'] if person['name'] == 'R2' else person['hobbies']
```

Comment: Condensing the if statement results in slowing things down as not only for 'R2' dictionary but for all dictionaries in list_dict a value has to be written to the dictionary. You even don't save lines of code by such condensing but sacrifice this way efficiency in terms of speed.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to loop over the lenght, you can loop through the list and you can condense with a one-liner if statement

```py
#!usr/bin/python3
from pprint import pprint
for person in list_dict:
    person['hobbies'].append('lubrification') if person['name'] == 'R2' else ...
pprint(list_dict)
>>> [
        {'name': 'Old Ben', 'age': 71, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['getting wise']},
        {'name': 'Han', 'age': 26, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['shooting']},
        {'name': 'Luke', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['being arrogant']},
        {'name': 'R2', 'age': 'unknown', 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ["lubrification"]}
    ]
```

you can also do this with a comprehension:

```py
[person['hobbies'].append('lubrification') for person in list_dict if person['name']]
```

But, if you just want to change one, you can use this code:

```py
m = next(i for i,person in enumerate(list_dict) if person["name"]=="R2")
list_dict[m]["hobbies"].append("lubrification")
```

Comment: The first doesn't work as it should ... it replaces all persons 'hobbies' with Ellipsis except for 'R2'. The second misses the `if person['name'] == 'R2'. The third makes things complicated and longer instead of shorter and gives an AttributeError because it misses to turn map() return value to a list.. **I suggest you just delete your answer.** as it confuses much more than it helps.

Comment: @Claudio the first was tested in python 3.10 and it all worked, don't you have tested it? Maybe you have thought that the if statement was within the method,

Comment: In  Python3.9 and first approach you get 'hobbies' of not R2 become Ellipsis. You need `else person['hobbies']` to overcome it. I wonder how it comes that there is no replacement with Ellipsis in Python3.10. Hmmm ... In the second method you can't replace 'hobbies' as assignment will give an Error. That is why you use .append(). In between you totally changed the third approach making my comment on it obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other answers here but in my eyes they don't really help a newbie seeking to shorten his code. I **don't suggest** to use the below proposed shortening except the looping over items in list instead of using indices, but to give here an answer with some maybe worth to know 'tricks' *(you can have more than one name pointing to same variable/object, you can iterate directly over items of a list instead using indices)* to a newbie here a shortened version of the code:

```
for p in l: 
    if p[n]=='R2': p[h]=['lubrication']
print(l)
```

and below all of the code using the proposed shortening with comments pointing out the 'tricks':

```
list_dict = [
        {'name': 'Old Ben', 'age': 71, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['getting wise']},
        {'name': 'Han', 'age': 26, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['shooting']},
        {'name': 'Luke', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': ['being arrogant']},
        {'name': 'R2', 'age': 'unknown', 'country': 'Space', 'hobbies': []},
        {'name': 'R2', 'age': 15, 'country': 'Alduin', 'hobbies': []}
    ]
l = list_dict; n='name'; h='hobbies'

# I would like to add a hobby to R2:
"""
for i in range(len(list_dict)):
    people = list_dict[i]
    if people['name'] == 'R2':
        people['hobbies'] = ['lubrication']
"""
# I got what I was expecting but as a newbie I'd like to learn a few 
# easy tricks to make it shorter: 

for p in l: # loop over items in list instead of using indices 
    if p[n]=='R2': p[h]=['lubrication'] # use short variable names
    #    ^-- give  --^ long string constants short names 
print(l)
```

Comment: use the constants in the square brackets, no need for variables

Comment: @XxJames07- yes, there is no need for variables, but if you are after shortening the text length of the code it is an option you can use.